# Search taking priority over naming file when saving in Nautilus

Tags: nautilus, files, filemanager, search

I'm using nautilus version 3.36.3 and I have an annoying problem when saving files: despite the name of the new file being highlighted in the name box, typing with my keyboard by default starts searching through the current folder. Is there a way to fix this so I don't have to do the extra click on the naming box every time I save something?

Comment: The name box is *not* nautilus. It is a GTK file save dialog. Please update your question. I cannot reproduce that on Ubuntu 21.10, so this behaviour may be corrected.

Comment: I have the same exact issue, is there a fix out there please ?

Answer (score 1):

As you have found, typing after "activating" the Nautilus file explorer will search the current directory for files or additional directories.

Within the save-file dialog, after navigating to your selected directory via "activating" the interactive Nautilus window, you can "activate" the file-to-be-saved filename entry bar by either clicking inside or utilizing the shortcut

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>L</kbd>

This is present in 18.04 LTS.

Comment: I think he means "doing such operations automatically", so your answer isn't the most on-topic one, but is a nice workaround.

Comment: Not happening for me on Ubuntu 21.10. Typing replaces the highlighted file name;  Ctrl+F  can be used to start search. Could have been changed.