# When saving a file, I can't type the new name even though the original name is highlighted

Tags: nautilus, files, 22.04

I'm using Files 42.2 on Ubuntu 22.04.

On 20.04, when saving a file, its original name was highlighted and I was able to directly type its new name and press ENTER to save. On 22.04, the original file name is still highlighted but typing does not work. I have to manually select the original file name before typing its new one.

How can I get Files/Nautilus to allow me to type the new file name without the extra clicks?

This similar question did not help me (CTRL + L does not work, and I do not use the same version): [Search taking priority over naming file when saving in Nautilus](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1340227/search-taking-priority-over-naming-file-when-saving-in-nautilus)

Thanks for your help!

Comment: This is a bug, happening only with containerized applications (snap, e.g Firefox). Note also that the File dialogs are *not* the file manager Files 42.2. You could remove Files and still have the dialogs - they belong to the graphical toolkit (GTK). No solution until the developpers fix this. Not using snaps, e.g., changing Firefox to the regular .deb version, is a way to avoid the issue.

Comment: @vanadium Sounds like an answer...

Comment: @Jos, I elaborated on this in another question, and I have marked this one as a duplicate of that.

Comment: @vanadium I see now. My apologies.

Comment: @Jos do not worry at all. You are welcome!

Comment: @vanadium Thank you for your help. I believe you are right. I just tried saving a document from another application and it worked perfectly. I will try the fix you are mentioning.

Comment: This might be a stupid question, but are there browsers that work well on Ubuntu 22.04 that do not use snaps?

Comment: @DMich yes: Firefox.